# General memory-barrier versus special volatile access (on AVR)

Tags: c++, volatile, interrupt-handling, memory-barriers, avr-gcc

In the follwing code I provide three versions of the function `getSeconds()`.

Version 1 uses a simple `cli`-assembler instruction (volatile) and volatile restore of `SREG` and a volatile access of the `seconds`. Please note, that there is no general memory-barrier here.

Version 2 also uses `cli()` but with a memory-barrier, so there is no need for special access to `seconds`.

Version 3 is essentially the same as Version 2 but useful for C-Code.

My question is, if there might be situations where Version 1 is more efficient, since if forces only a reread of `seconds` in the case it is called, whereas Version 2 (and 3) impose a general memory-barrier and so force all cached register-values to be written to the memory.

```
#include <avr/cpufunc.h>
#include <util/atomic.h>
#include <stdint.h>

template<typename T>
volatile T& volatile_access(T& v) {
    return static_cast<volatile T&>(v);
}

namespace Atomic {
    struct DisableInterruptsRestore final {
        inline DisableInterruptsRestore() {
            cli(); // memory-barrier inside
        }
        inline ~DisableInterruptsRestore() {
            SREG = save; // only-volatile
            __asm__ volatile ("" ::: "memory");  // barrier added
        }
    private:
        uint8_t save{SREG};
    };
    struct DisableInterruptsRestoreNoBarrier final {
        inline DisableInterruptsRestoreNoBarrier() {
            __asm__ __volatile__ ("cli"); // only volatile, no barrier
        }
        inline ~DisableInterruptsRestoreNoBarrier() {
            SREG = save; // only volatile, no barrier
        }
    private:
        uint8_t save{SREG};
    };
}

namespace {
    uint32_t seconds;
    //V1
    uint32_t getSeconds() {
        Atomic::DisableInterruptsRestoreNoBarrier di; // volatile
        return volatile_access(seconds);// volatile
    }
// V2
//    uint32_t getSeconds() {
//        Atomic::DisableInterruptsRestore di; // is general memory-barrier
//        return seconds;
//    }
// V3
//    uint32_t getSeconds() {
//        ATOMIC_BLOCK(ATOMIC_RESTORESTATE) {
//            return seconds;
//        }
//        return 0;
//    }
}

ISR(TCA0_CMP1_vect) {
    seconds += 1;
}

int main(void) {
    while (true) {
        if (getSeconds() > 100) {
            GPR_GPR0 = 0x01;            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know you question is about efficiency, but I would prefer simplicity over obscurity and vote for option 3).

Comment: `__asm__ __volatile__ ("cli"); // only volatile, no barrier` will happen to work because: 1. it's volatile, so ordered wrt. a `volatile` access to `SREG`.  2. GCC7 and later has an implicit `"memory"` clobber for non-empty GNU C Basic asm statements (no operands or clobbers), to be more forgiving to frequently-buggy code that uses GNU C Basic asm inside functions that aren't `__attribute__((naked))`.  See a comment on [Why can't local variable be used in GNU C basic inline asm statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/115735895), and earlier in that comment thread.

Comment: And see https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended for recommendations on never using it, always Extended so you can be explicit about what you mean, using a `"memory"` clobber or not to tell the compiler whether or not it can reorder at compile time with loads/stores in compiler-generated asm.  For enabling / disabling interrupts, no you don't want that.

Comment: You need both 1) volatile access to seconds or barriers before and after access -- to re-read seconds every time (sure, volatile is more efficient as does nor break optimization for other code) and 2) disabled interrupts to avoid changing of seconds by interrupt in the middle of reading.